# Форма обратной связи Django не передается в feedback.html, что не так?

Tags: python, django

Нужна форма обратной связи методом POST с полями "Название сообщения", "Отправитель(email)","Сообщение", кнопкой "Отправить". Есть код, который за это отвечает. Но в feedback.html ничего не отображается, кроме кнопки "Отправить" и лейблов. Не пойму, где ошибка.

*views.py*

```
def feedback(request):
    return render_to_response('feedback.html')


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField()
    copy = forms.BooleanField(required=False)


def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            copy = form.cleaned_data['copy']

            recipients = ['dkorytkin@gmail.com']

            if copy:
                recipients.append(sender)
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
            except BadHeaderError:  
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')

            return HttpResponse('Thanks for feedback')
    else:

        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'feedback.html', {'form': form})
```

*feedback.html*

```
{% block feedback %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div>
          <label for="id_subject">Тема:</label>
          {{ form.subject.errors }}
          {{ form.subject }}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="id_sender">E-mail:</label>
          {{ form.sender.errors }}
          {{ form.sender }}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="id_message">Сообщение:</label>
          {{ form.message.errors }}
          {{ form.message }}
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ form.copy.errors }}
          <label for="id_copy">Отправить копию себе {{ form.copy }}</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'feedback.views.feedback', name='feedback'),
)
```

*settings.py*

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-pulse.com:2525'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из Вашего urls.py следует, что при запросе вызывается функция views.feedback:

```
def feedback(request):
    return render_to_response('feedback.html')
```

Эта функция просто отдает шаблон и не передает в него ни один параметр. Шаблон же работает с формой, соответственно переменная form должна была передаться в шаблон. Поэтому у Вас и отображается только label и button.

Могу предположить, что в Вашем случае правильная функция `contactview()`, ее и нужно записать в роут.

Comment: решил проблему:urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'feedback.views.contactView', name='feedback'),
)